# diagnosing key binding problems in Vim

Tags: vim, customization, key-bindings

I'm working on mappings in vim and ran into a problem.  I can map to `<Up>`, `<Down>`, `<Left>`, and `<Right>`, and I can map to `<S-Left>` and `<S-Right>`, but I can't map to `<S-Up>` and `<S-Down>`.  In other words

```
:nmap <S-Right> l
```

works, and so does

```
:nmap <Up> l
```

but

```
:nmap <S-Up> l
```

doesn't.

Maybe SO will know the answer to this problem, in which case I'll change the question title to be more specific. But failing that, I'd like commands I can use to diagnose what's failing where.

(if I broke your up key with the above command, type `:unmap <Up>`)

Comment: Mapping `k` will work for `shift-k` and vice versa. In other words, mapping shift with a key will work the same way as if you have mapped only the key. So, shift-up is same as up. Try mapping `k`. And use `shift-k` to see that the mapping worked for shift-k even though you mapped for `k`.

Comment: You may try alt or Ctrl with other keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue probably is with your terminal [settings].

What you can do to troubleshoot is trying to literally insert the keys received by Vim. In insert mode, type `<C-V>` followed by the (shifted) cursor key. For me (gnome-terminal with `TERM=gnome-256color`), I get these distinct values (so shifted cursor keys all work for me, yay):

```
" Up, S-Up, Down, S-Down
^[OA ^[[1;2A ^[OB ^[[1;2B

" Left, S-Left, Right, S-Right
^[OD ^[[1;2D ^[OC ^[[1;2C
```

If you see the same values for shifted and unshifted keys, your terminal doesn't distinguish between them, so Vim cannot, neither. The next step would then be to check your terminal settings / use a different terminal.

Comment: Equally you might not see them at all if your window manager or terminal is catching them first.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The problem was in my terminal settings: my terminal had rules to tell S-Left and Left, but not S-Up from Up, and that difference was clear in the results from C-V.  I knew about C-V but not that it should be able to tell the difference.